# Reaching an ImageView in SimpleCursorAdapter View Binder

Tags: android

First of all I am very new to view binder in simple cursor adapter and guess i am doing something silly that is causing my problem. I have this simple cursor adapter as shown below and i am using a view binder to apply some dynamic effects to the list items. Now first two statements of if works fine. But i am unable to reach the imageview at any cost. Tried a lot of alternatives.

```
final SimpleCursorAdapter reminders =
            new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.detail_row, remindersCursor, from, to);
        setListAdapter(reminders);

    reminders.setViewBinder(new SimpleCursorAdapter.ViewBinder() {

        public boolean setViewValue(View aView, Cursor aCursor, int aColumnIndex) {



            if (aColumnIndex == 1) {
                String get_title = aCursor.getString(aColumnIndex);
                TextView textView = (TextView) aView;
                textView.setText("Country: " + get_title);
                return true;
            }
            if(aView.getId() ==R.id.custom_date ) {
                String get_date = aCursor.getString(aColumnIndex);
                TextView textView1 = (TextView) aView;
                textView1.setText("Time now: " + get_date);


                return true;
            }
            if(aView.getId() == R.id.custom_type){

                String get_type = aCursor.getString(aColumnIndex);
                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) aView.findViewById(R.id.custom_icon);
                if(get_type.matches("ASIA")){
                    Picasso.with(ReminderListActivity.this).load(R.drawable.asia).into(imageView);
                } else if (get_type.matches("ROW")){
                    Picasso.with(ReminderListActivity.this).load(R.drawable.rest).into(imageView);
                }
                return true;
            }


            return false;
        }
    });
```

Meanwhile R.layout.detail_row has below:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal" >



    <ImageView

        android:id="@+id/custom_icon"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/callback" />



            <TextView
                android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
                android:id="@+id/custom_title"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="12sp"
                android:text="" />


            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/custom_date"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="10sp"
                android:text="" />
            <TextView
                android:gravity="center"
                android:id="@+id/custom_type"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textSize="1sp"
               android:text="TextView" />
```

Comment: Please add the code that sets up `from` and `to` in the adapter constructor so we can see what is in those variables.

Comment: thanks @krislarson... it was here where the problem occured

Answer (score 0):

Solved it myself. Problem was in my "to" configurations. I have a typo error. Instead of defining the fields as R.id.custom_icon (image field), i had called the comparison field R.id.custom_type by mistake. Feel like an idiot.

Wrong code:

```
final int[] to = new int[]{R.id.custom_title,R.id.custom_date,R.id.custom_type};
```

Corrected code:

```
final int[] to = new int[]{R.id.custom_title,R.id.custom_date,R.id.custom_icon};
```